# Can the President of the US pardon everyone?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, president, pardon

Can the President of the United States pardon everyone? For example, let's say a criminal organisation is committing crimes, after awhile they get raided by the police, everyone gets arrested and convicted, can the president of the US pardon everyone in that organisation?

Comment: Depends on what they were convicted for, and which court convicted them.

Comment: @Trish actually it was answered in the Answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

The President can pardon everyone (with the possible exception of himself) of crimes, and can pardon people by category rather than by name.

But, the President can only pardon federal crimes that have been committed and are mentioned in the pardon. However, the federal crimes do not have to have resulted in convictions or even charges to be pardonable.

Many mass pardons of this type were made after the U.S. Civil War. Another notable mass pardon was of draft dodgers after the Vietnam War was over by President Carter.

The President cannot (in the opinion of many, it hasn't been authoritatively resolved) pardon himself. The President cannot pardon a state or local crime or a crime against the law of another country. The President cannot use the pardon power to eliminate the right of one person to sue another person. The President cannot pardon a crime that was not committed at the time that the pardon was issued.

Comment: Thank you, Can the President Of The US Pardon Someone Several Times, for example the President Pardons the members of a criminal organization, then they get convicted again and again for another crime several times, can The President Pardon them as many times as he wants to.

Comment: @Zheer Yes. Obviously, a President can only serve a certain number of a years and loses the power when a new President takes office, so there are some limits to this and it has almost never happened in practice.

Comment: Thank you, Really helpful, so the President Of The US cant get impeached for pardoning criminal organization several times right?

Comment: The President can be impeached for anything that Congress believes constitutes a valid basis for impeachment in its political judgment which is not subject to judicial review. The legal standard for impeachment is "high crimes and misdemeanors." Many members of Congress would consider the kind of unprecedented conduct that you are suggesting to be impeachable. No prior President has ever tried to do what you suggest repeatedly pardoning members of a criminal organization and most crimes violate both federal and state laws, and the President can't pardon violations of state laws.

Comment: note tht double jeopardy does *not* prevent the state from convicting someone pardoned by the president for convicting the person again for the same offence if it is also a state crime. For example, a drug dealer could be convicted by a federal court and a state court for one and the same act. The second convicting court could also fasttrack the trial by usinge the first trial's evidence and outcome as deposition.

Comment: @Trish Is it possible to get convicted twice at the same time by both federal and state court for a crime that is both a federal and  a state crime? You end up spending twice  the time in prison?

Comment: @Zheer Yes. Half in a state, half in a federal prison.You could *also* be conviced by a military court a *third* time for the same thing and spend another sentence in a military prison.

Comment: @Trish I'm pretty sure that double jeopardy prohibits conviction for the same offense by a civilian criminal court and a military court for the same offense.

Comment: @ohwilleke oh, it is a different offense that the military court convicts you over that you commit by doing the same act: most criminal acts count as *conduct prejudicial to good order and discipline* and that is a different charge for the same act.

Comment: Can the president pardon corporations?

Comment: @gerrit No idea. Corporations are so rarely charged criminally and to my knowledge it has never been done. But i don't obviously see a reason why he couldn't.

Comment: "But, the President can only pardon federal crimes that have been committed and are mentioned in the pardon." Though they don't have to be explicitly listed. Nixon's pardon is an example of a fairly non-specific, but nevetheless valid pardon. The relevant part of the text reads: "Now, THEREFORE, I, GERALD R. FORD, [...] do grant a full, free, and absolute pardon unto Richard Nixon for all offenses against the United States which he [...] has committed or may have committed or taken part in [...] from January 20, 1969 through August 9,1974." (some words omitted for length and readability)

Comment: @AlexC How much detail is sufficient is a question that has to be resolved on a case by case basis. There are no doubt many cases where if push had come to shove a description might have been held be a court to be too vague to apply to a specific charge, but where the uncertainty is enough to cause a prosecutor aware of the pardon to refrain from bringing charges, without making precedent. In general, there are all sorts of legitimate legal interpretation issues that are issues of first impression (i.e. issues with no precedent providing a binding resolution of the question) in pardon law.

Comment: @ohwilleke Very true, and I hope I didn't come across as disagreeing with you. It's more a caveat that I felt was worth a mention.